# JQuery UI Drag and Drop (get Draggable value to show and hide textarea box)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Great day! I have a simple function using jquery ui to exhibit drag and drop function. I would like to drag two images (two divs) into a screen (a div). The goal is when image #1 is dragged and dropped on the target, the screen will show the textarea box and while the other is dragged into the same screen, the textarea is disappeared. jsFiddle example Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jengunfan/mgLTu/3/)!

I try to add "if(condition)" syntax to differentiate the two different status. However, it doesn't work at all. My scripts are as follows:

```
<script>
  $(function() { 
  $(".sample").draggable({ 
  revert: true     
  });

   $("#screen").droppable({ 
      tolerance: 'touch', 
      over: function(event, ui){ 
       $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over'); },
         out: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out'); }, 
          drop: function(event, ui) {
                        //I believe something is wrong here!
              var idVal=$(ui.draggable).attr('id');
                if ( idVal=="sample6"){     
                  $('#text').show();}
                  else if(idVal=="sample5"){
                $('#text').hide();}

                  }

                });
                 }); 
  </script>
```

The HTML markups are as follows:

```
<div id="screen" style="float:left">

<div id="text" class="textarea" ><textarea  style="border:hidden; color: yellow; background-color: transparent; z-index:1000px;">Text Here!</textarea>

</div>
</div>

<div id="memo"></div>

<div id="sample6" class="sample">
  <p>Show the Textarea</p>
</div>
<div id="sample5" class="sample">
  <p>Delete the Textarea</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know if Jquery UI can let me drop different objects with 2 or more "id" to single droppable area to fire/trigger different results ("such as show or hide a textbox or change images"). Any helpful suggestion or solution is welcome!

Comment: could you post a fiddle?  I tried to build one but too hard to guess on css stuff

Comment: I have attached the link for jsFiddle example of this script at top of the page.You can see there is a screen and draggable buttons under it. I want to drag the "textarea" button to the screen to show the textarea (shown in the screen) and then hide the textarea when the "delete textarea" box is dragged and dropped into the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this jsFiddle accomplishes what youre asking about here.  Keep in mind you'll still have to work out setting the textarea to defaultly not shown if thats what you want.  Also, I changed the css in the fiddle to be easier to work with.

Basically, I just did a console.log(idVal) to see that you were getting the proper id ("sample6 and sample5"), but only checking for the number at the end of the id, so I changed your if statement to compare against the proper ID's.  It looks like you may be trying to use data attributes as well, but you only have one on the last draggable element.

[Thats what I did in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgLTu/5/)

**NEW DROP PARAMETER OF #screen droppable**

```
  drop: function(event, ui) {
      var idVal=$(ui.draggable).data('num');
      console.log(idVal);//you can remove this
      if ( idVal=="sample6"){     
          $('#text').show();
      }
      else if(idVal=="sample5"){
        $('#text').hide();
      }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This is a powerful fix!